# JAWS doesn't read placeholder

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am using JAWS to test the code. JAWS reads the below date as "Move In Date star `dd/mm/i`-edit".

How do I make JAWS read it as "Move In Date star `dd/mm/yyyy`".
JAWS doesn't read `"yyyy"`, instead it reads "i edit".

```
<input type="text" aria-label="Move In Date * dd/mm/yyyy" id="startDate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it should be the `aria-label` that's read and not `placeholder`, according to the ["Accessible Name and Description Computation 1.1" spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2), but some screen readers will read both the label and placeholder.  Others will read only the label.

Step 2C of the spec says to use `aria-label` and then process then stops.  (The spec is a big if/else statement.)  Step 2D is where `placeholder` ***might*** be used.  That's where *"native markup...text alternative"* is used.  It's debatable whether `placeholder` should be considered alternative text, but nonetheless, step 2D should never be reached if step 2C is satisfied.

JAWS might be saying "my" instead of "i", but it's still not correct.  After you hear it, press <kbd>Ins+Space</kbd> then <kbd>H</kbd> to bring up JAWS' speech history window.  It should show the exact text that's read, which should be your `aria-label`.

Two things you can try:

1. Adjust your "punctuation" verbosity setting in JAWS.  The default is "most".  I don't remember if "most" will cause "/" to be read.  You can try changing it to "all" if you're not hearing "slash" to see if that breaks up the "mm" from the "yyyy".
2. Use uppercase letters in `aria-label` for the date specification.  Sometimes JAWS will spell out the letters when words are in all caps if the word is not a pronounceable word.

`<input type="text" aria-label="Move In Date * DD/MM/YYYY" id="startDate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">`

Comment: Thank you!!!. I changed the 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'DD/MM/YYYY' and that worked. JAWS now reads it correctly. Thank you again!!!!!

Comment: Glad it worked but it’s a trick that would have to be thoroughly tested with NVDA and VoiceOver to see if it has any adverse affects. Hopefully you are testing with more than one screen reader.

Comment: I am using JAWS and NVDA. Things work in NVDA with ease. It is JAWS that has some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use upper case letters in the date mask, e.g. YYYY. JAWS will read them as individual letters.

You shouldn't need to do anything else, although I'd recommend you use a regular label element construct with your input, rather than aria-label.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for the answer! Could you elaborate why it is better to use a regular label here?

Comment: Your answer is just repeating the answer from 2 years before you posted.  It already said to upper case the YYYY.  As far as using a `<label>` instead of `aria-label`, there is no basis for your suggestion that one is better than the other. One benefit that the `<label>` gives you is that mouse users can click on the label text and it will move the keyboard focus into the field. Other than that, the accessible name of the input field is exactly the same whether you have a label or aria-label.